# rubyzip - cannot load such file -- zip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubyzip

I am attempting to use rubyzip to create zip archives on the fly in my app. I'm using [their readme](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip) as a starting point. I added the gem to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rubyzip'
```

Then ran `bundle install` and restarted the rails server.

My controller code is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'zip'

filename = "#{Time.now.strftime('%y%m%d%H%M%S')}"
input_filenames = ["#{filename}.txt"]
zip_filename = "#{filename}.zip"

Zip::File.open(zip_filename, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
  input_filenames.each do |f|
    zipfile.add(f, directory + '/' + f)
  end
end
```

The error I'm getting is: `cannot load such file -- zip`

I've tried `require 'zip/zip'` but it produces the same error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: don't `require 'rubygems'`, bundler takes care of that for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Commenting out `require 'zip'` gives me `uninitialized constant ... ::Zip` error.

Comment: you still need `require "zip"` (what version of rubyzip are you using btw?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might be looking at an example that's too new.

If you are using [Rubyzip 0.9.x](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/tree/0-9-x-stable), then you need to follow [this example](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/tree/0-9-x-stable#usage):

(`require "zip/zip"`, then use `Zip::ZipFile` instead of `Zip::File`)

```
require 'zip/zip'

folder = "Users/me/Desktop/stuff_to_zip"
input_filenames = ['image.jpg', 'description.txt', 'stats.csv']

zipfile_name = "/Users/me/Desktop/archive.zip"

Zip::ZipFile.open(zipfile_name, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) do |zipfile|
  input_filenames.each do |filename|
    # Two arguments:
    # - The name of the file as it will appear in the archive
    # - The original file, including the path to find it
    zipfile.add(filename, folder + '/' + filename)
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked perfectly. I am using 0.9.9. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Looks like the gem docs are out of date, b/c they have `Zip::File.open(zipfile_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|` but after looking at the source code, `Zip::ZipFile...` is correct.  I'll let them know.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you to use:

```
gem 'rubyzip',  "~> 1.1", require: 'zip'
```

and then `require 'zip'` in your controller should work fine.

Comment: Don't forget to restart your server.

Answer (score 2):

Interface of rubyzip was changed. You using old version. Docs on rubydoc.info from master branch.